# Neural Networks for Audio/Sound Augmentation

Tags: audio, architecture, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

What type of neural net architecture would one use to map sounds to other sounds? Neural nets are great at learning to go from sequences to other sequences, so sound augmentation/generation seems like it'd be a very popular application of them (but unfortunately, it's not - I could only find a (fairly old) magenta project dealing with it, and like, 2 other blog posts).

Assuming I have a sufficiently large dataset of input sounds / output sounds of the same length, how would i format the data? Perhaps train a CNN on spectrograms (something like cycleGAN or pix2pix), maybe use the actual data from the WAV file and use an LSTM? Is there some other type of weird architecture no one has heard about that's good for sound? Help me out please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else doing a similar thing - the answer is using fast fourier transforms to get the data into a manageable state, and then people usually use RNNs or LSTMs to do stuff with the data - not CNNs.